# how to make it reset by itself? stacking Hex-number

Tags: for-loop

I am new and tried this. code is like this:

```
    var displayHex = document.getElementById('hex-number');
    var hexButton = document.getElementById('hex-btn');
    var hexs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 'a','b','c','d','e','f'];

    var bodyBgd = document.querySelector('body');

    hexButton.addEventListener('click', getHexNumber, false);
         let frontHex = '#';

    function getHexNumber() {
       for (let i=0; i<6; i++){
       let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*hexs.length);
       frontHex += hexs[random];
       }
       bodyBgd.style.backgroundColor = frontHex;
       displayHex.innerHTML = frontHex.toUpperCase();
   }
```

when I press button, backgroundcolor changes as Hex-number displays. but the hex-number is not reseting after trial.  the more I press, the more it just keep stacking like this "#583782BD90D877612C8960540.....
anyone can help me?

Comment: Move `let frontHex = '#';` inside your `getHexNumber()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with that language but it's pretty easy to catch the problem, what you doing is that you defined a variable, then adding characters to it in loop without clearing the original variable!! The result is that, the characters stack, to solve this problem you have to initilize the variable with some value at start of loop!

### For your case, your code will look like:

```
var displayHex = document.getElementById('hex-number'); 
var hexButton = document.getElementById('hex-btn'); 

var hexs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 'a','b','c','d','e','f']; 
var bodyBgd = document.querySelector('body'); hexButton.addEventListener('click', getHexNumber, false); 
    let frontHex = '#'; 

function getHexNumber()
 { 
     for (let i=0; i<6; i++){ 
     let frontHex = '#'; 
     let random=Math.floor(Math.random()*hexs.length); 
     frontHex += hexs[random]; 
} 

bodyBgd.style.backgroundColor = frontHex; 
displayHex.innerHTML = frontHex.toUpperCase(); }
```